# Delete Table Room Synchronously

Tags: android, android-room

I have the following code:

```
mDatabase.repo().insertCustomers(DataGenerator.generateCustomers());
int a = mDatabase.repo().deleteCustomers();
if(a==0){}
```

It seems that `a` has still the size of the inserted data. Delete Query with an Integer as a returned value is supposed to be Synchronous, but it isn't. Any ideas?

**My repoDao**

```
@Transaction @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertCustomers(List<Customer> customers);

@Query("DELETE FROM Customer")
int deleteCustomers();
```

Comment: Review|Help and Improvement: I edited.

Answer (score 0):

The return value represents how many rows were deleted, as written in Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query).

> UPDATE or DELETE queries can return void or int. If it is an int, the value is the number of rows affected by this query.

Comment: Irrelevant with my question.

Comment: This is not what the question is about

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Well, you say that `a` has the size of the inserted data, which means that is was removed from the database synchronously.

Comment: @GeorgePaouris Also you don't have to use `@Transaction` on insert DAO method as it is always run inside a transaction.